# display all ie versions under one application

Tags: .net, html, css, cross-browser

I had an application/browser that would show me the website under different versions of IE

I would select which version and it would display the page through the lenses of that version

Not able to find the program, can you please point it to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) is what you are looking for.

Please note, that it is not perfect and the "official" standard for testing different IE versions is to run virtual machines with one browser version per machine.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Windows-Tool called MultipleIE, where you can run multiple versions of IE on one computer. Perhaps not what you looked for, but suitible for intranet-pages or testing on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

you can try
http://finalbuilds.edskes.com/iecollection.htm

I use it and i am very happy! (not by using IE, but being able to test all the versions for Bugs)